# Kindly check the R command

Tags: r

I am doing following in Cooccur library in R.

```
> fb<-read.table("Fb6_peaks.bed")
> f1<-read.table("F16_peaks.bed")
```

everything is ok with the first two commands and I can also display the data:

```
> fb
> f1
```

But when I give the next command as given below

```
> explore_pairs(c("fb", "f1"))
```

I get an error message:

```
Error in sum(sapply(tf1_s, score_sample, tf2_hits = tf2_s, hit_list = hit_l)) : 
  invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

Could anyone suggest something?

Comment: My R is rusty, but did you mean to write `explore_pairs(c(fb, f1))` without the quotes, maybe?

Comment: It doesn't work without quotes .

Comment: Which package is explore_pairs in? A quick google and search of cran doesn't shed any light on what you're using; if you can give a link to the help page, we'll be able to see the details for the method

Comment: Cooccur package, please see this article http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2910723/ . It works very well with the example dataset.

Comment: I have managed to install the file published with that paper, but am having trouble understanding the methods it contains; without any formal help files (and, specifically in your case, what data structures example_pairs() expects), it's difficult to give any suggestions.  You may be best emailing the paper authors directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite promising to release a version to the Bioconductor depository in [the article the authors published over a year ago](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/11/359), they have still not delivered. The gz file that is attached to the article is not of a form that my installation recognizes. Your really should be corresponding with the authors for this question.

The nature of the error message suggests that the function is expecting a different data class. You should be looking at the specification for the arguments in the `help(explore_pairs)` file. If it is expecting 2 matrices, then wrapping `data.matrix` around the arguments may solve the problem, but if it is expecting a class created by one of that packages functions then you need to take the necessary step to construct the right objects.

The help file for explore_pairs does exist (at least in the MAN directory) and says the first argument should be a character vector with further provisos:

```
\arguments{
      \item{factornames}{an vector of character strings, each naming a GFF-like
      data frame containing the binding profile of a DNA-binding factor.
```

There is also a load utility, `load_GFF`, which I assume is designed for creation of such files.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I will see it.  It is not user friendly at all :(

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work, only that it is not suitable for installing "out of the box" on my GUI set-up.

Answer (score 0):

Try rename your data frame:
names(fb)=c("seq","start","end")

Check the example datasets. The column names are as above. I set the names and it worked.